# Get the Class type for dynamic type?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-data

I wrote some code :

```
    public static object func()
    {
        return new { a = 1, b = 2 };
    }

   Console.WriteLine((func() as dynamic).a); //returns '1'.
```

If I can do : `func() as dynamic` so dynamic should be some kind of reference type  / class.

I looked for its Class type but couldn't find any (via reflector).

what is its type ? ( reference type) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the type via GetType() as normal.

That is an anonymous type, which is (as an implementation detail) a form of generic type. The name of the type is deliberately unpronounceable in c#.

If you look in reflector, there is probably an internal generic type somewhere ending in ’2 (to indicate 2 generic type parameters), with two properties "a" and "b", of the first and second generic type arguments respectively. It is a class, so a reference-type.

As a note:

```
new { a = true, b = 123.45 }
```

Would actually use the same *generic* type but with different generic type parameters.

Also; using `dynamic` doesn't change the **object** - it only changes how it is accessed.

Comment: as int is an Alias to Int32 , does dynamic is an Alias to xxx ?

Comment: @Royi ah, but things can actually **be** an int/Int32 (maybe boxed). No object is ever actually *of type dynamic*. In the same way that no object *is of type IFoo* (an interface). A **variable** (or expression) is of type dynamic; that just tells the compiler how to work with it - it doesn't *change* the actual object.

Comment: what is a real life scenario for which I will use dynamic ( not expando , and not in the context of return type of function) ? I know all the objects which im working with so what is the scenario in rel life which a "new unknown type" will come to me and I will have to deal with ...?

Comment: @Royi COM or talking to an object from a dynamic language (Iron* maybe) would be good examples. Also, there are some fun things you can do with pattern-based methods - see Simple.Data. In most routine code, an interface would be a preferable abstraction